# My application style changes when i run it on emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

i'm kind of knew in application developting.
I'm having trouble When i'm styling the application layout. it looks good. good as the way i want the appliaction to be.
but when i'm trying to run it the all application messedup all jumps to the left top of the app, anyone knows why?
[image: IMG 1]

[image: IMG 2]

This is the layout xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="tech.XXX.LoginA">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Tech name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="49dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="49dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bLogin"
        android:layout_width="321dp"
        android:layout_height="98dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:text="Login"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="32dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="151dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out RelativeLayout. I recommend using RelativeLayout in your case. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html   You can find other tutorials as well.